# 'An' or 'a' when followed by information between commas

Tags: commas

In the following sentence, I'm unsure whether to use ‘*an*’ or ‘*a*’.

> ..primarily meant as **a**, albeit large, donation.

On the one hand ‘*an*’ sounds more appropriate when read, as the vowel beginning to ‘*albeit*’ suggests.
Alternatively, one might say ‘*a*’ is correct; is a sentence not supposed to make perfect sense with the word between the commas removed. If so, it must be just an ‘*a*’.

I'm tilting towards the latter, even though it sounds odd. Please enlighten me.

Comment: I find this specific example awkward – I simply wouldn't phrase a sentence that way – but I've run into the same problem in similar circumstances, like parenthetical asides. In those cases, I usually choose words to avoid this a/an clash. I'm not sure what the correct rule is when they don't match, but in a pinch I'd choose the sound of the nearest word. For example, in “a difficult opponent,” you use _a_ to match the adjective, not _an_ to match the noun.

Comment: That makes sense. I think English is one of the areas in which a real solution isn't the only one. Thanks!

Comment: Choosing between *a* and *an* is our [most frequently asked question ever](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent). It gets asked several times a week, every week. And the answer is always exactly the same, and embarrassingly trivial to boot. We even have [a blog post](http://english.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/articles-a-vs-an/). So please do search the site before posting. Thank you.

Comment: The linked duplicate is actually a very poor question and answer: although it *says* it is about a/an before a parenthesis, the example given is not parenthetical. This question here, on the other hand, gives an example which *is* parenthetical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you stuck with this very awkward sentence construction? Since you are questioning what article to use, I suspect you are not. Therefore, I suggest that you change the sentence construction:

```
     ....primarily meant as a donation, albeit a large one.
```

That gets you around all of your problems.

Comment: Yeah, this seems the sensible consensus here. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The choice between *a* and *an* is not one of grammar, or orthography. It is a purely phonological choice depending wholly on the following sound. The following sound here is /ə/- a vowel, so the form selected is *an*.

Comment: Well, now we can have a discussion. I'm leaning more this way now though.

Comment: +1 It's more obvious to pronounce it this way if you remove the commas, but I think rewording along @terpy's lines is still better.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would opt for *... primarily meant as **an**, albeit large, donation.*, for two reasons:

1. If you actually *speak* the phase, saying ***a*** is awkward, whereas saying ***an*** comes naturally.
2. If you had a straight adjective, instead of an adjectival phrase, there would be no question that the article should correspond to the adjective, not to the noun: e.g. ***an anonymous donation***. Why should the present of an adjectival phrase, instead of an adjective, make any difference to the rule?

Alternatively, you could rephase the expression to:

> ***... primarily meant as a donation, albeit a large one.***

Comment: Thank you. The second point especially makes a lot of sense.